# Is there a way to suppress DBCC TRACEON/OFF messages in the Error Log?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, dbcc, error-log

We have quite a few dataloading processes that run throughout the day all day long.  These processes are setting the 610 flag on for their connection then turning it off when they are done.  Because these messages are put into the ERROR LOG, our ERROR LOG is growing quite a bit.  We've tried using the WITH NO_INFOMSGS parameter of DBCC but it still puts the entry in the ERROR LOG (even though it doesn't put it in the query output).

Any ideas?

The messages look like this:

> Date      10/23/2014 8:32:46 AM Log       SQL Server (Current - 10/23/2014
>   8:31:00 AM)
>
> Source        spid57
>
> Message DBCC TRACEON 610, server process ID (SPID) 57. This is an
>   informational message only; no user action is required.

...

> Date      10/23/2014 8:32:54 AM Log       SQL Server (Current - 10/23/2014
>   8:31:00 AM)
>
> Source        spid57
>
> Message DBCC TRACEOFF 610, server process ID (SPID) 57. This is an
>   informational message only; no user action is required.

Comment: Have you thought about just turning it on once for the instance?

Comment: There is a Microsoft Connect item to have 610 converted into a query hint; seems like a good idea.  https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/557515/trace-flag-610-functionality-should-be-implemented-as-a-hint

Comment: @MaxVernon You can actually use some trace flags as query hints. `SELECT * FROM TableName OPTION(QUERYTRACEON 9481);`  Not sure if it works with 610 but I don't see why it wouldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

trace flag 2505 can be used. Wrote a blog post with experiment http://sqlserver-help.com/2014/12/09/help-how-to-suppress-dbcc-traceonoff-messages-in-the-error-log

Comment: You should perhaps include the pertinent points from that blog entry just in case it goes away in future.